# SQL Greatest N Per Group with Extra Criteria

Tags: sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm stuck on something I think should be quite simple, I've been searching for a while in the Greatest-N-Per-Group tag and general google-fu and am unable to find something that quite fits.

I have a query that (in a simplified form) take a table of data and performs aggregations/groupings on it, but I want to bring in a unique identifier based on the max value of a different column.

To give example of what mean:

```
Uniq Value Time Person
1    6     180  Bob
2    8     170  Bob
3    4     45   Claire
4    4     90   Claire
```

The current query would be:

```
SELECT Person, SUM(Time) AS Duration 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Person
```

What I need to add to this result set is the Uniq and value of the largest value per person, I.e. the result set would look like:

```
Person Duration Value Uniq
Bob    350      8     2
Claire 135      4     3
```

I initially thought I could join the initial results set to a subquery containing the max(value), person and uniq, but I then run across the problem of returning one result per Uniq, instead of the one per-person but only uniq where the row is the max value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this deterministicly you need to join back to your table:

```
SELECT  MaxT.Person,
        MaxT.Duration,
        T.Value,
        MIN(T.Uniq) AS Uniq
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT Person, SUM(`Time`) AS Duration, MAX(Value) AS Value
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY Person
        ) MaxT
            ON MaxT.Person = t.Person
            AND MaxT.Value = t.Value
GROUP BY MaxT.Person, MaxT.Duration, MaxT.Value;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba0496/1)**

Comment: Wish I had the reputation to upvote for this - it works like a charm and is close to what I had already (I just had the Uniq inside the subquery) though it took me a full 15 to follow it though and work out why taking the uniq out to the main query worked!

Comment: @David, don't worry, I'll upvote for both of you ! +1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Person, SUM(TIME) AS Duration, MAX(VALUE) AS `value`, MAX(Uniq) AS Uniq
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Person
```